# I wanted to do remote access in mysql kubernetes to create the tables

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm creating a mysql pod in kubernetes and I accessed **kubectl describe svc mysql** to see the endpoints but even though I know the endpoints I can't do remote access with HeidiSQL I'll post my yamls below to see if anyone can help me.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:myql
        name: mysql
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
#      secret:
#        secretName: mysql-pass
#        items:
#        - key: password
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
#  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

I wanted to do remote access in mysql kubernetes to create the tables

Comment: Tip: [Port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: `kubectl exec` allows you to run a command directly on your pod: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec. You will want something like `kubectl exec -it <podname> -- mysql -u<username> -p` at which point you will be running the mysql cli directly in your pod.

Comment: Thank you all do you know how do I connect pods to this mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Mr @Jerry 's answer there are two ways which you can use

**FIRST**

[kubectl exec docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec)

```
kubectl exec -it <podname> -n namespace -- <command> -<arguments-as-per-command>
```

**SECOND**

In case it is temporary and you want to do it using some client on your local, you can proxy the pod network to your local

[kubectl port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward)

```
$ kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <port-on-pod>:<your-local-port>
```